# In PowerShell, how do I convert DateTime to UNIX time?

Tags: datetime, powershell

In PowerShell, how can I convert string of DateTime to sum of seconds?

Comment: What do you mean by "sum of seconds"? UNIX time (seconds since epoch)?

Comment: yes, I mean to UNIX time

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
PS H:\> (New-TimeSpan -Start $date1 -End $date2).TotalSeconds

1289923177.87462
```

New-TimeSpan can be used to do that. For example,

```
$date1 = Get-Date -Date "01/01/1970"
$date2 = Get-Date
(New-TimeSpan -Start $date1 -End $date2).TotalSeconds
```

Or just use this one line command

```
(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: what are the diffrents between Get-Date and [System.DateTime]? in my apps I used by [System.DateTime].

Comment: Nothing, AFAIK. Get-Date is equal to [DateTime]::Now and Get-Date -Date "01/01/1970" is equal to [DateTime]::Parse("01/01/1970")

Comment: Unix time is based on UTC, so the last line should use $date2.ToUniversalTime(). It would also be useful to prefix the whole thing with [int].

Comment: Wouldn't they both be UTC? If so, does it make a difference in the distance between two date time objects in the same time zone?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57487299/4534493 - if you are using PS 5.1

Answer (score 61):

With .NET Framework 4.6 you can use [`ToUnixTimeSeconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds.aspx) method of `DateTimeOffset` class:

```
[DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()

$DateTime = Get-Date #or any other command to get DateTime object
([DateTimeOffset]$DateTime).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
```

Comment: i ended up using this:
```$fromEpoc = [DateTimeOffset]::Now.AddHours(-1).ToUnixTimeSeconds()*1000;

$toEpoc =  [DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()*1000``` The return values work on the https://www.epochconverter.com/ site converter to verify the correct time is returned ;)

Answer (score 35):

As mentioned, the UNIX Epoch is January 1st, 1970 at 12:00 AM (midnight) **UTC**.
To get the current seconds-since-the-epoch in UTC in a whole-number I use this 80-character one-liner

```
$ED=[Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s"))
```

The code above is PowerShell 2.0 compliant & rounds-down (to ensure consistent behavior w/ UNIX)

Comment: Just noticed my #necromancer badge was from this answer. Glad everyone likes it :)

Comment: This definitely does not give the correct UNIX timestamp in my Powershell v3 (neither seconds nor milliseconds). I don't know how this got so many upvotes?!

Comment: @lazlev You may have misread; the above code returns a UNIX-compatible "Seconds since the Epoch (Jan 1st 1970 in UTC) In PowerShell v2, v3 and v4. I've just confirmed this.  Keep in mind that the 80-char one-liner stores the value in a variable, so it's not updated every time you check $ED (to do that, you'd need to use a function instead)

Comment: That looked good, but actually it's unreliable, because the number of digits is not constant. At the beginning of my development, I had to divide $ED by 10000 to get seconds, but now it's 100000. I didn't debug, I now use the solution of Keith Hill below.

Comment: @ocroquette I'm not sure where you're seeing inconsistent digits in the output from above. `$ED` is going to be fixed at ten-digits since the output is a 32-bit string. Which should hold you till the year 2038 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

Comment: @Signal15 like I said, at first it seemed to work, even though it wasn't neither seconds nor milliseconds. Then at some point for an unknown reason, the unit changed, and I got milliseconds. It looks like the problem lazlev had above.

Comment: Problem is the cast. `Get-Date(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -uformat "%s"` returns `1448965807,05586` while `[decimal](Get-Date(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -uformat "%s")` return  `144896580705586`. I recommend Keith Hills answer instead, it works and it is much more clear what happens.

Answer (score 32):

Not sure when `-UFormat` was added to [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Date) but it allows you to get the date and time in UNIX epoch timestamp format:

```
[int64](Get-Date -UFormat %s)
```

It's supported by both the PowerShell and PowerShell Core.

Comment: Hopefully this bubbles up to the top somewhere

Comment: `-uformat %s` is there in PS 5.1, not sure about earlier versions, so at least since Jan 2017

Comment: `[int64](Get-Date(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s)` fixes the timestamp when you are not in UTC timezone.

Comment: Does already exist in Powershell 3.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-3.0

Comment: `-uformat` exists in Powershell 2.0

Answer (score 22):

This one-liner works for me (compared it to http://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

```
[int64](([datetime]::UtcNow)-(get-date "1/1/1970")).TotalSeconds
```

For milliseconds

```
[int64](([datetime]::UtcNow)-(get-date "1/1/1970")).TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: Nice! 63-characters, I like it!

Comment: Your cast to int64 is unnecessary as that's already the type.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley I cannot confirm this. `(([datetime]::UtcNow)-(get-date "1/1/1970")).TotalMilliseconds | Get-Member` yields `TypeName: System.Double` in my PowerShell version and displays a decimal value.

Answer (score 18):

To get seconds since 1970 independent of time zone, I would go with:

```
$unixEpochStart = new-object DateTime 1970,1,1,0,0,0,([DateTimeKind]::Utc)
[int]([DateTime]::UtcNow - $unixEpochStart).TotalSeconds
```

Answer (score 10):

I just wanted to present yet another, and hopefully simpler, way to address this.  Here is a one liner I used to obtain the current Unix(epoch) time in UTC:

```
$unixTime = [long] (Get-Date -Date ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()) -UFormat %s)
```

### Breaking this down from the inside out:

#### (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

This gets the current date/time in UTC time zone.  If you want the local time, just call *Get-Date*.
This is then used as input to...

#### [long] (Get-Date -Date (UTC date/time from above) -UFormat %s)

Convert the UTC date/time (from the first step) to Unix format.
The **-UFormat %s** tells *Get-Date* to return the result as Unix epoch time (seconds elapsed since January 01, 1970 00:00:00).  Note that this returns a *double* data type (basically a decimal).  By casting it to a *long* data type, it is automatically converted (rounded) to a 64-bit *integer* (no decimal).  If you want the extra precision of the decimal, don't cast it to a *long* type.

#### Extra credit

Another way to convert/round a decimal number to a whole number is to use *System.Math*:

```
[System.Math]::Round(1485447337.45246)
```

Comment: Slow - you call `get-date` more than once, while you can address a `[DateTime]::Now` or `[DateTime]::UtcNow` to get current date, the use the cmdlet just for formatting, which is also not without a caveat - non-english local culture might return an incorrent conversion result.

Comment: [int]$(Get-Date -UFormat %s)

Answer (score 7):

Powershell

```
$epoch = (Get-Date -Date ((Get-Date).DateTime) -UFormat %s)
```

Comment: Would you be able to help me out with using this in an Invoke-Expression Cmdlet ? I receive the following error ...Unexpected token '-Uformat' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:219
+ ... meUtc -Uformat %s}},@{e={$_.Length}} -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 5000
+                    ~~
Unexpected token '%s' in expression or statement.   I have posted a question on stackoverflow and I can link you to that for more information.

Comment: This is quite inefficient. `(Get-Date).DateTime` returns a string, which then has to be parsed again by the second call to `Get-Date -Date` (and string parsing dates is slow).

Comment: And it's not even necessary to pass the current date and time in the `-Date` parameter because when the parameter is omitted, the cmdlet is actually using the current date and time! The parameter is needed only when you need to specify a different time than the current one. So the correct and efficient version is `Get-Date -UFormat %s`. The result is same.

Answer (score 4):

For sending data to Grafana I needed the Unix Epoch time as 32 bit Integer from UTC. The best solution in the end was this:

```
$unixtime = (get-date -Date (get-date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s).Substring(0,10)
```

This results in a string, but can easy converted to an integer:

```
[int]$unixtime = (get-date -Date (get-date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s).Substring(0,10)
```

I tested this against an Ubuntu machine. The results from the commands above and the Linux command

```
date +%s
```

are identically.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following, which is based on ticks (Int64), rather than seconds (Int32), to avoid the Year 2038 problem. [Math]::Floor is used, as Unix time is based on the number of whole seconds since the epoch.

```
[long][Math]::Floor((($DateTime.ToUniversalTime() - (New-Object DateTime 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, ([DateTimeKind]::Utc))).Ticks / [timespan]::TicksPerSecond))
```

Comment: This gives me an error about null-valued expressions.

Comment: @thund: `$DateTime` must be set to a valid date-time before executing the above, e.g. call `$DateTime = Get-Date` then the above script.

Comment: Yes, that works. I didn't notice the undefined variable. I just lazily assumed my version of powershell didn't like it for some other reason.

Comment: Note that the floor function doesn't return an integer type; it's still whatever type [timespan]::TicksPerSecond is, which probably means double.

Comment: johan-boulé: That's true, which is why the output from `[Math]::Floor` is cast to `long`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a script which converts both TO and FROM CTIME that I've been using for a while (longer, because it was written for a "new to scripting" type crowd, with various comments.

```
# Here's a very quick variant to 'get the job done'
[Int64]$ctime=1472641743
[datetime]$epoch = '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
[datetime]$result = $epoch.AddSeconds($Ctime)

write-host $result

# A few example values for you to play with:
# 1290100140 should become ... 2010-11-18 17:09:00.000
# 1457364722 should become ... 2016-03-07 15:32:02.000
# 1472641743 should become ... 31/08/2016 11:09:03

# For repeated use / calculations, functions may be preferable. Here they are.

# FROM C-time converter function
# Simple function to convert FROM Unix/Ctime into EPOCH / "friendly" time
function ConvertFromCtime ([Int64]$ctime) {
    [datetime]$epoch = '1970-01-01 00:00:00'    
    [datetime]$result = $epoch.AddSeconds($Ctime)
    return $result
}

# INTO C-time converter function
# Simple function to convert into FROM EPOCH / "friendly" into Unix/Ctime, which the Inventory Service uses.
function ConvertToCTime ([datetime]$InputEpoch) {
    [datetime]$Epoch = '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
    [int64]$Ctime = 0

    $Ctime = (New-TimeSpan -Start $Epoch -End $InputEpoch).TotalSeconds
    return $Ctime
}
```

Hope that helps, especially if you just want something that's a little friendlier for beginners or so :).

Comment: Beginners will have a hard time understanding the term "C-time".

Answer (score 1):

Below cmdlet will convert the windows uptime into Unix understandable epoch time format:

```
   $s=Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | select csname,@{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION{$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}};
   [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date($s.LastBootUpTime.ToUniversalTime()).ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s"))
```

Comment: An uptime is a duration, not a date. Seems Microsoft messed up the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

This one should also work since javascript uses milliseconds since epoch :

```
ConvertTo-Json (Get-Date) | ? { $_ -Match '\(([0-9]+)\)' } | % { $Matches[1]/1000 }
```

Step by Step :

```
PS P:\> Get-Date

lundi 15 janvier 2018 15:12:22


PS P:\> ConvertTo-Json (Get-Date)
{
    "value":  "\/Date(1516025550690)\/",
    "DisplayHint":  2,
    "DateTime":  "lundi 15 janvier 2018 15:12:30"
}

PS P:\> (ConvertTo-Json (Get-Date)) -Match '\(([0-9]+)\)'
True
PS P:\> $Matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
1                              1516025613718
0                              (1516025613718)
```

Comment: That's got to be the most obfuscated and fragile way to do it. M'enfin!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Uformat parameter of get-date. But first I like to be sure the date of a given workstation is correct (I consider a workstation connected to a company network where there is a server with a correct time set).

```
#Synchronize workstation time with server
cmd /c "sc config w32time start= auto"
cmd /c "w32tm /unregister"
cmd /c "w32tm /register"
cmd /c "net start w32time"
cmd /c 'tzutil.exe /s "W. Europe Standard Time"'
cmd /c 'reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation" /v DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f'  
cmd /c "net time \\full-servername.ru /set /yes"
```

Then I get the actual unix timestamp to compare objects (accounts) between actual date and creation date (account deletion tasks when unix timestamp exceeds limit date)

```
#Get actual unix timestamp and compare it to something
$actual_date = (get-date -UFormat "%s")
$final_date = "some unix date of the database"
if(($final_date - $actual_date) -lt 0 ){
#make deletion task
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A culture-independent, and actually pretty fast answer:

```
[int64]([double]::Parse((get-date -uformat "%s"),[cultureinfo][system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentculture))
```

This invokes some .NET "magic" when it comes to actually produce a formatted string, it gets converted to double using current thread's culture settings, then it converts to int64 which by default does exactly floor the double provided. Should you desire a UTC timestamp, use `-date ([DateTime]::UtcNow)` in `get-date` to use current UTC time as the time to convert.

```
[int64]([double]::Parse((get-date -date ([DateTime]::UtcNow) -uformat "%s"),[cultureinfo][system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentculture))
```

PS: Unless you really need a string as your output, having an integer is overall better to *your* programming culture.

Answer (score 1):

[Signal15's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25916431/615422) is a bit verbose for me. I did it this way:

```
[int] (Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -uformat '%s')
```

Answer (score 1):

tested work well with different timezone:

```
(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().Subtract((Get-Date "01/01/1970")).Totalseconds
# or
[DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()
```

below is **NOT** recommend because it only works on timezone GMT+0

```
 Get-Date -UFormat %s
```

BTW, we can also verify the EPOCH UNIX time if you installed python:

```
python -c "import time;print(time.time())"
```

Comment: Do weird stuff like that ((Get-Date(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s) -split ',')[0]

Comment: [long](Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().Subtract((Get-Date "01/01/1970")).Totalseconds

Comment: better [math]::Round((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().Subtract((Get-Date "01/01/1970")).Totalseconds)

Answer (score 0):

Again comparing to http://www.unixtimestamp.com and building on others above

```
$date1 = (Get-Date -Date "01/01/1970").ToUniversalTime()
$date2 = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$epochTime = [Math]::Floor((New-TimeSpan -Start $date1 -End $date2).TotalSeconds)
```

Comment: Creating the 01.01.1970 in YOUR Timezone with 00:00:00 and THEN converting it to universaltime might be anything but timestamp "0".

Answer (score 0):

Late answer...

Hare are both convert functions `ConvertTo-UnixTime` & `ConvertFrom-UnixTime` for convenience (both pipeline capable)

```bsh
function ConvertFrom-UnixTime () {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, Position = 0)]
        [Int64]$UnixTime
    )
    begin {
        $epoch = [DateTime]::SpecifyKind('1970-01-01', 'Utc')
    }
    process {
        $epoch.AddSeconds($UnixTime)
    }
}

function ConvertTo-UnixTime {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, Position = 0)]
        [DateTime]$DateTime
    )
    begin {
        $epoch = [DateTime]::SpecifyKind('1970-01-01', 'Utc')
    }
    process {
        [Int64]($DateTime.ToUniversalTime() - $epoch).TotalSeconds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

culture-indiferent
PowerShell handles milliseconds well

```
    [DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
    [math]::Round((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().Subtract((Get-Date "01/01/1970")).TotalMilliseconds)
    [double]::Parse((get-date -uformat "%s"),[cultureinfo][system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentculture).ToString().Replace(',','').Replace('.','').substring(0,13)
    [double]::Parse((get-date -date ([DateTime]::UtcNow) -uformat "%s"),[cultureinfo][system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentculture).ToString().Replace(',','').Replace('.','').substring(0,13)
    [string](Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -uformat '%s').ToString().Replace(',','').Replace('.','').substring(0,13)
    [math]::Round((([TimeSpan]((Get-Date(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime())-(New-Object -Type DateTime -ArgumentList 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))).TotalMilliseconds))
```

For my codes, I use a reverse conversion script(time-zoned included):

```
    $VALstring = [DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
    try{
        $null=[bigint]$VALstring 
        try{
            $origin = New-Object -Type DateTime -ArgumentList 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
            $unixTime = $origin.AddSeconds($VALstring)
            $unixTime=Get-Date $unixTime -Format "ddd, dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff"
        }catch{
            try{
                $unixTime = $origin.AddMilliseconds($VALstring)
                $unixTime=Get-Date $unixTime -Format "ddd, dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff"           
            }catch{
                $unixTime=''
            }
        }
        try{
            function ConvertFrom-UnixTime {
                [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "Seconds")]
                param (
                    [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "Seconds")] [int] $Seconds,
                    [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "Miliseconds")] [bigint] $Miliseconds
                )
                Begin { $date = (Get-Date "1970-01-01 00:00:00.000Z")}
                Process {
                    switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
                        "Miliseconds" { $date = $date.AddMilliseconds($Miliseconds) }
                        Default { $date = $date.AddSeconds($Seconds) }
                    }
                }
                End { $date }
            }
            Set-Alias -Name epoch -Value ConvertFrom-UnixTime
            $unixTimeZoned=$VALstring | epoch
            $unixTimeZoned=Get-Date $unixTimeZoned -Format "ddd, dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff"
        }catch{$unixTimeZoned=''}
    }catch{}
    "unixTime = $unixTime"
    "unixTimeZoned = $unixTimeZoned"
```

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is interested in getting milliseconds since Unix epoch, my approach is something like this

```
[int](Get-Date -UFormat %s) * 1000 + (Get-Date).Millisecond
```