# Last one week data from today's date - syntax error

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am trying to pull last 7 days of data from today's date from LTM using powershell script. Instead of inserting the specific start time and end time, I am trying to do it automatically to get data from  7 days back up till today. So far I have tried following.

```
$Query = New-Object -TypeName iControl.SystemStatisticsPerformanceStatisticQuery
$Query.object_name = "throughput"
$Query.start_time = (get-date).AddDays(-7)
$Query.end_time = get-date
$Query.interval = 0
$Query.maximum_rows = 0
```

but I am getting a following error:

```
Exception setting "start_time": "Cannot convert value "2/22/2017 12:26:35 PM" to type "System.Int64". Error: "Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int64'.""
At line:1 char:1
+ $Query.start_time = (get-date).AddDays(-7)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

Comment: well, the error says it, it is probably looking for unix time, try this: `$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7); [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -Date $date -UFormat %s))`

Comment: I need to specify start_time and end_time, when use it i am getting an error. I have modified the syntax that you provided as follows.  $Query.start_time = (get-date).AddDays(-7); [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -Date $Query -UFormat %s))  and error is The property 'start_time' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.     ..... I am new to scripting still trying to figure out

Comment: no, you are doing it wrong. `$Query.start_time = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -Date ((get-date).AddDays(-7)) -UFormat %s))`

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it giving me an error  $Query.start_time = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -Date ((get-date).AddDays(-7)) -UFormat %s))
The property 'start_time' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set. .......... and end time .........  $Query.end_time = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -Date (get-date) $Query -UFormat %s))
Get-Date : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '3/1/2017 2:06:51 PM'.

Comment: well, you obviously don't know what you are doing, do a `$query | gm` and post output in your answer

Comment: nono, edit your answer, why is $query object an datetime object? you did something wrong

Comment: I am getting the same result from $Query | gm .. I posted the whole script here http://stackoverflow.com/q/40727333/2769144

Comment: can we continue in the chat?

Comment: Sure, but I have 8 reputation, and getting message not yet enough to chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$query.start_time = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -Date ((get-date).AddDays(-7)) -UFormat %s))
```

as I said in the comments, its expecting unixtimestamp, well we gave him that.