# PowerShell: use command output + string as filename

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, stream, streamlink

I have a windows program which can download streams, I specify the output. Would like to use as output filename the [epoch time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192971/in-powershell-how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-unix-time) + extension (for example mp4). I've tried this example but doesn't work:

```
PS C:\>streamlink --hls-live-restart -o (Get-Date -Date ((Get-Date).DateTime) -UFormat %s)+".mp4" URL best
```

How can I format the filename properly?

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is it doing?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself. The filename has to be output from `$()` and perform all concatenation operations inside:

```
PS C:\> echo (Get-Date -Date ((Get-Date).DateTime) -UFormat %s)+".mp4"
1585338575
+.mp4
```

```
PS C:\> echo $((Get-Date -Date ((Get-Date).DateTime) -UFormat %s)+".mp4")
1585338562.mp4
```

Proper command:

```
streamlink --hls-live-restart -o $((Get-Date -Date ((Get-Date).DateTime) -UFormat %s)+".mp4") URL best
```